# How do I put out an variable in FPDF? (PHP)

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am trying to use FPDF, but it doesn't work, whenever I would like to put out a variable in the PDF.

Here is my code:

```
<html> 
<head><title>FPDF</title></head>
    <body> 
<?php
    
    //I would like to print out the text in the variable

    echo "Would you like to convert to php?";

    $enteredText = "This is some example text";

    if ($_GET["action"]=="yes") {

        ob_start();
        require('fpdf.php');

        // Instantiate and use the FPDF class
        $pdf = new FPDF();
        
        //Add a new page
        $pdf->AddPage();
        
        // Set the font for the text
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 18);
        
        // Prints a cell
        $pdf->Write(5, $enteredText);
        
        // return the generated output
        $pdf->Output(); 
        ob_end_flush(); 
        
    }

    else if ($_GET["action"]=="no") {
       
        
    }

?>
        <a href = "Trying.php?action=yes"><button>yes</button></a>    
        <a href = "Trying.php?action=no"><button>no</button></a>
 
        <form id="form" action="Trying.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Text"><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Enter"><br />
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

So, I tried to print out the given variable $enteredText in the PDF, but it just doesnt work. It works when I write it like this:

```
$pdf->Write(5, "This is some example text");
```

But it just doesn't work if I put an variable instead of the text.

How do I print out the variable in an PDF with FPDF? I researched, but I couldn't find anything.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your code works just fine for me.

Comment: Don't output any HTML before the PDF.